# Color reproduction on Google Glass while in fullscreen mode

Tags: google-glass

Anyone noticed colors changing when going to a fullscreen (no status bar) mode?  Colors in my app change from drastically.  I using the fullscreen theme in the AndroidManifest.  Also noticed when the app starts and stops there is a brief time where the colors are the right color.

```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: I have noticed this. I thought it was my Glass, so I ordered a replacement.

Comment: I am seeing this also on my device. Seems to correct itself when an OS graphic element like the menu bar or mouse cursor are present. So probably not a hardware thing.